# Is it necessary to add Google Map Api key in release->res->values

Tags: android, performance, google-maps

I have created API key for Google Map, I created SHA-1 for android studio, and added it in `map console`, then i grabbed SHA-1 of play store, and also added in `google map console`.

I added the key in Mainifest file.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIax3ug4ut...." />
```

Now my question is, do i also need to add keys in `release->res->values->google_maps_api.xml`, or is it fine to add keys in just `manifest` file.

I am also able to view map on signed apk after adding the key on Manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessary.

It's just more structured instead of hardcoded. When you have to change the API-Key and you use it in different locations in your project than it could be useful to change it just once instead of multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, so its fine if i just update the key in Manifest file, and leave the keys as is `google_maps_api.xml`

Comment: @Kirmani88 You have to change the API-Key then also in the `google_maps_api.xml` file. Then it would be useful to add it to the values that you have to change it just once when have to.

Comment: let make it simple, I am not going for useful way, I just want to be sure that this will work fine on production, So If i update the key in `manifest` file, and does not touch `google_maps_api.xml` at all, then every thing will work fine on signed apk. right?

Comment: @Kirmani88 You have to provide the API Key just on the manifest that's right. I did not include the `google_maps_api.xml` in my project and this app is already on the Play Store and works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much @Julian , 1 final question, what if there is some random key already added in `google_map_api` that is different from the key that i added in `manifest` file. Will this make any impact on Map. For now its working fine for me.

Comment: @Kirmani88 No this hasn't any impact. Google Maps takes the API Key from your manifest anyway except you linked the file as well in the manifest.